# getTransactionDetails fails when sending PNREF from payflow

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I use the payflow api to charge credit cards, I receive and store the PNREF. I need to retrieve the fee paypal deducts from my sale which is not returned in payflow's response. I setup credentials and a signature for the API and proceeded to use the getTransactionDetails method to retrieve the FeeAmount. I can authenticate but when sending the 12 char PNREF I get the following error:

```
Error: The transaction id is not valid
```

I think the API is expecting 17 characters but I only have 12. Is it possible for payflow and the paypal API transactions to interoperate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GETTRANSACTIONDETAILS API is a PayPal API and it accepts a 17 character long ID to be passed . If you have the PayPal as the Processor and you use the Payflow API's then you will get the PNREF and the PPREF in the response parameters. You need to use the PPREF as the transaction ID in the GETTRANSACTIONDETAILS API to make it work .